# org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No unique service matching interface org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory found.

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I am trying to deploy the springboot application in Pivotal Cloud Foundry. I am getting following exception.

Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No unique service matching interface org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory found. Expected 1, found 0

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'rabbitConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No unique service matching interface org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory found. Expected 1, found 0

Comment: It's just saying the it can't find a service bound to your app. Did you create & bind a RabbitMQ service instance to your app instance? What type of service is it? Who's the provider?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry** maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```